# SQL Server Native Client 11 ADO connection string for MS SQL Server 2014 with integrated login

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic, database-connection, ado

I'm currently trying to migrate a working web solution from an environment on IIS 7.5 and MS SQL Server 2008 R2 (both on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64) to IIS 8.5 and MS SQL Server 2014 (both on Windows Server 2012 R2).

I can't quite get my ADODB connectionstring working in the new environment. I used the following string in the old environment:

```
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=myDB;Data Source=myServer"
```

I've tried with the following string:

```
strConn = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;DataTypeCompatibility=80;Trusted_Connection=yes;MARS Connection=False;Initial Catalog=myDB;Data Source=myServer"
```

but that results in the following error when trying to open the connection:

> -2147217843 Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

The web site is set up with a special IIS application pool that is using a domain account that has been granted permissions on the SQL server. I can see in the SQL Server log that it is trying to use anonymous logon instead of using the account specified in the application pool.

I then tried to change my connection string to the following:

```
strConn = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;DataTypeCompatibility=80;Integrated Security=True;MARS Connection=False;Initial Catalog=myDB;Data Source=myServer"
```

That makes the logon part successful, but instead I get the following error:

> -2147217887 Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done

The rest of my code to open the connection looks like this:

```
Set objConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 10
objConnection.Open strConn
```

I've searched various sites for suggestions, but none have so far worked for me. https://www.connectionstrings.com does not contain anything specific to SQL Server 2014.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the following connectionstring to work:

```
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;DataTypeCompatibility=80;Integrated Security=SSPI;MARS Connection=False;Initial Catalog=myDB;Data Source=myServer"
```